# when is titanium damaged by use on gas stove?

Tags: canister-stoves, titanium

I tried boiling tap water in a [Snow Peak Trek Titanium Bowl](https://www.snowpeak.com/products/trek-titanium-bowl-stw-003t) on low heat over a [Kovea Spider](https://mercatorgear.com/product/kovea-spider-standard/).

The Spider has steel pot supports which sit in the flame and glow red-hot during use.

The bowl acquired indelible "dot" marks **inside**, at locations that correspond to the contact points with the supports.

Is this purely cosmetic or is the bowl becoming damaged by the localised heat?

Comment: Titanium is usually fine for much higher temperatures, and generally uncoated. But because that product isn't marketed for cooking, it may have something unusual about it

Comment: @ChrisH thanks. I emailed snow peak a few days ago but haven't heard back yet, so posted in case the broader question might be interesting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least in this instance, the marks are purely cosmetic.

Snow Peak tell me there is no technical reason I can't use the bowl to boil water over a stove but that "it may not be particularly well suited for this type of heat source". I should not be concerned about the discoloration: the surface may oxidise and patina but "typically, this will not damage the bowl".

---

**double-walled vessels should not be heated**

I may have had in the back of my mind information such as:

- [Keith](https://keitheurope.com/en/products/double-walled-mugs): *not suitable for direct heating*
- [Snow Peak](https://www.snowpeak.com/collections/mugs/products/titanium-double-450-mug): *cannot be used for cooking or placed over a heat source*

but this will be due to the double wall not the titanium.

Comment: My snow peak pot is all loads of colors and works just fine. It's just part of using Titanium. They make great ultralight cookware.

Comment: @noah that's good to know

Comment: Yes, trying to cook in a double wall container will at best waste fuel and at worst damage the outside wall or any insulation if its not vacuum insulated.

Comment: @jhnc You should mark this as the accepted answer - it gives you a bonus or a badge for asking and self-answering I think.

Comment: @bob1 cheers, was just giving some time for extra info to emerge (eg. what are these coatings that could be problematic? or perhaps someone has experienced damage to other titanium vessels)